# In a HTML document, find a "text" appearing after another "text" using xpath in Java & Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

The HTML code is as follows -

---

```
<div><a href=""><span>Eligible ITC</span></a></div>
    <div><a href=""><span>(A) ITC Available</span></a>
    <div id="demo4a">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Integrated Tax</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>(1) Import of goods</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div><a href=""><span>(B) ITC Reversed</span></a>
    <div id="demo4b">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Details</th>
                    <th>Integrated Tax</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>(1) As per rules 42 & 43 of CGST/SGST Rules</td>
                    <td>5,32,467.00</td>
                </tr>                       
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

To locate the 'table' present inside 'div id="demo4a"', my requirement is -

---

STEP 1 : First locate the text "Eligible ITC" 
STEP 2 : Then locate the text "(A) ITC Available" using the fact that it appears after the text "Eligible ITC"
STEP 3 : Then locate the first 'table' immediately following the text "(A) ITC Available"

To locate the 'table' present inside 'div id="demo4b"', my requirement is -

---

STEP 1 : First Locate the text "Eligible ITC"
STEP 2 : Then locate the text "(B) ITC Reversed" using the fact that it is appears after the text "Eligible ITC", which is followed by the text "(A) ITC Available"
STEP 3 : Then locate the first 'table' immediately following the text "(B) ITC Reversed"

What I have tried till now using the "following" xpath axes in Java & Selenium-

---

---

To locate the 'table' present inside 'div = "demo4a"'

---

FOR STEP 1 :

```
           WebElement tableLocator = 
            gstr3bFullPageData.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(text())='Eligible ITC']")
            );
```

FOR STEP 2 : -------- NO IDEA HOW TO DO IT !!! --------

FOR STEP 3 :

```
       List<WebElement> table4_a_Data = 
           tableLocator.findElements(
               By.xpath("following::table[1]")
           );
```

What I have tried till now using the "following" xpath axes in Java & Selenium-

---

---

To locate the 'table' present inside 'div = "demo4a"'

---

FOR STEP 1 :

```
WebElement tableLocator = 
    gstr3bFullPageData.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(text())='Eligible ITC']")
    );
```

FOR STEP 2 : -------- NO IDEA HOW TO DO IT !!! --------

FOR STEP 3 :

```
List<WebElement> table4_a_Data = 
    tableLocator.findElements(
        By.xpath("following::table[1]")
    );
```

My problem is how to locate a text (as in STEP 2) that appears after another text (as in STEP 1) using the "following" xpath axes (as in STEP 3) ?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks to all who have replied to my query. After going through the suggestions given by all of you and after doing some trial and error, I could come up with the exact requirement that I was looking for.

My code now looks like this - 
'''
WebElement table3_1Data = 
    gstr3bFullPageData.findElement(By.xpath("//*/following::*[text()='4. Eligible ITC']/following::*[text()='(A) ITC Available (whether in full or part)']"));

List<WebElement> asd = table3_1Data.findElements(By.xpath("./following::table[1]"));
'''

Comment: Here, I am first locating the text '4. Eligible ITC'. This text can be anywhere in the HTML document. Then without taking the help of any tags i.e. div, span, etc., I am locating the text '(A) ITC Available (whether in full or part)'. This text can also be present anywhere in the HTML document except that I MUST come after the text '4. Eligible ITC', not before it. For this, I am using the "following" xpath axes.

Comment: Likewise, I can use this chain to step through as many texts as I want to, in order of their location within the HTML document, without making the use of any absolute or relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XPATH locators like

`//*[@id='demo4a']/table`

If you must use the text to identify the table, try like

`(//*[text() = 'Eligible ITC']//..//..//..//table)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Xpath for retrieve "(A) ITC Available" element:

```
//div[.//span[text()="Eligible ITC"]]//span[1]
```

or

```
//div[.//span[text()="Eligible ITC"]]//span[contains(text(),"(A)")]
```

---

Get the "table" element:

> following-sibling: Selects all siblings after the current node

```
//div[.//span[text()="Eligible ITC"]]//div[.//span[contains(text(),"(A)")]]/following-sibling::div[1]/table
```

or

```
//div[.="Eligible ITC"]//div[contains(.,"(A)")]/following-sibling::div[1]/table
```

Comment: No it does not have to be "following". But I must reach the desired "table" only by using the "texts" in order of their occurrence in the HTML doc.

Comment: I am also trying to avoid the use of any "id" or "class" to locate the "tables".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added my comment under the my main query. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
WebElement tableLocator = gstr3bFullPageData.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(text())='Eligible ITC']"));


WebElement table4_a = tableLocator.findElement(By.xpath("./a[.='(A) ITC Available']"));
WebElement table4_a_Data = table4_a.findElement(By.xpath("./following::table[1]"));


WebElement table4_b = tableLocator.findElement(By.xpath("./a[.='(B) ITC Reversed']"));
WebElement table4_b_Data = table4_b.findElement(By.xpath("./following::table[1]"));
```

For `a` and `b` table you can use `id`, and no need to use relative xpath:

```
WebElement tableA = gstr3bFullPageData.findElement(By.cssSelector("#demo4a table"))
WebElement tableB = gstr3bFullPageData.findElement(By.cssSelector("#demo4b table"))
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using any "id" to locate the tables. I want to use only the "texts" sequentially (in order of their location in the HTML doc) to reach to the desired "table".

Comment: Ok. Than try first code without using id and with sequentially locating

Answer (score 0):

I think the following expressions meet your stepping requirements.

To get your first table, try this xpath expression

```
//div/a/span[text()='Eligible ITC']//following::div/a/span[text()='(A) ITC Available']//following::div[1]/table[1]
```

To get the other, try

```
//div/a/span[text()='Eligible ITC']//following::div/a/span[text()='(B) ITC Reversed']//following::div[1]/table[1]
```

And, if you want both in the same expression, try:

```
//div/a/span[text()='Eligible ITC']//following::div/a/span[text()= '(A) ITC Available' or text()= '(B) ITC Reversed']//following::div[1]/table[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am looking for an expression which can detect the second text i.e. "(A) ITC Available" directly from the first text i.e. "Eligible ITC", without using any absolute paths. For example I can reach the first text directly by the expression "//*[normalize-space(text())='4. Eligible ITC']". From here I want to reach the second text directly i.e. without using any specific path like div/a/span etc.

Comment: The reason for the above requirement is that in the original HTML doc, there are numerous div and span tags inbetween the first and the second text. So I don't want to be dependent on those tags as I am not sure how many of them are there. Instead I want to jump from one text to another text following it.

Comment: @Ripon - I'm not sure I entirely understand you. I edited the expressions (by changing a `/` to `//`) to address what I think is your problem. See if that works. If not, I'm afraid you may have to edit your question to add more html code to show the problem.